# How to use parameterized function call for ajax slideshow extender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, slideshow

I am using the ASP.NET ajax slideshow extender tool for displaying images slideshow. I followed the video tutorial and have taken reference [from here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/SlideShow/SlideShow.aspx).

I have the GetSlides function defined as:

```
public AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides(string parms) {
-----
-----
}
```

In the aspx page i need to pass the parameter value which is in the query string for that page. The code i used to pass the parameter to the function is:

```
<ajax:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender1" runat="server"
         AutoPlay="true" ImageDescriptionLabelID="lblImageDescription"
               Loop="true" NextButtonID="Btn_Next" PlayButtonID="Btn_Play" 
                PlayButtonText="Play" PreviousButtonID="Btn_Previous" 
                 SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides(<%= Request.QueryString["tempID"] %>)" StopButtonText="Stop"
                  TargetControlID="Image1">
</ajax:SlideShowExtender>
```

However this provides the basic error of server constructs:  `Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs`.

I have checked the expression builder concept also using the text like: `"<%$ AppSettings: FooText %>"`, through web.config. But the parameter is itself dynamic and cannot be stored in web config file. So how should I pass the querystring parameter for the GetSlides function?

Comment: And i always thought that AjaxControlToolkit has become obsolete when jQuery was born.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set parameter from codebehind. Use ContextKey property:

```
SlideShowExtender1.ContextKey = Request.QueryString["tempID"];
```

Also, your method must have signature:

```
 public AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides(string contextKey)
```

It's all in docs.